# How do I send up debian sendmail to use google Apps smtp to by pass ISP blocking smtp

Tags: php, sendmail, google-apps

I have a debian webserver and it is running shopsite and some php programs. Which use sendmail to send out email to customers. So this server only needs to send email out. So how do I setup sendmail to use Google Apps smtp? Because I am getting the following error: sm-mta stat=Deferred: Connection reset by mx4.hotmail.com

Comment: This may not be the answer you're looking for, but certain MXs (hotmail is a prime example) require a delay (typically a few seconds) between two e-mails sent. One of our apps solves this by building special queues for such hosts and only sending e-mails to them in a specified interval (eg. 30 sec).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't gotten it set up yet, the easiest way to do it is ditch sendmail, install postfix, and then set up the Google Apps SMTP server as your smarthost. IIRC, the default postfix config has a fully-commented config file, so you just need to read through it, uncomment the smart host line, put in the Google SMTP server, and you're done.

Otherwise, you still need to set up Google Apps as your smarthost. There's a ton of Google-able info on how to do this; see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-sendmail-as-a-smart-host/) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make Google your MTA, as far as I know.

Try using [sSMTP](http://www.delodder.be/howto/gmail-with-ssmtp-on-deb-based-system/)